# Missing packages after upgrading ASP .NET 5 to beta-7

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm developing a web site using the ASP .NET 5 platform. The site's target framework at the moment is dnx451. Some time ago I upgraded to beta-7 runtime version and now I have a problem with a couple of packages: System.Reflection.Primitives and System.Resources.ResourceManager. The versions of those packages for net45 are absent, in other words I have only an empty file named "*.*" in the ".dnx\packages\System.Reflection.Primitives\4.0.0\lib\net45" folder in my profile, and the same is for another package. It does not affect developing the site in Visual Studio, but I have troubles when publishing and deploying the site. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you share how your project.json looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all the packages under `.dnx\packages` and run `dnu restore` (or restore from VS)

Comment: Victor, thank you for your help! I found in the end that nuget feed was not configured properly in my deployment server, but your advise helped me to resolve my problem locally and to track down the issue on the server.